Django 404 using get_queryset()
This is part of my views.py
class CommentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        event_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        comment_id = self.kwargs['comment_pk']
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        queryset = Comment.objects.filter(event=event, id=comment_id)
        return queryset
    
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

This is the url:
path('<int:pk>/comments/<int:comment_pk>/', views.CommentDetail.as_view(), name='comment-detail'),

This is the model:
class Comment(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE , related_name='comments_for_event')
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author} on {self.event.title} : {self.content}'

I'm getting a 404 response for some reason with this endpoint:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/2/messages/3/
I tried to add a print statements like this:
class CommentDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        event_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        comment_id = self.kwargs['comment_pk']
        print('Event ID:', event_id)
        print('Comment ID:', comment_id)
        event = Event.objects.get(id=event_id)
        queryset = Comment.objects.filter(event=event, id=comment_id)
        print('Queryset:', queryset)
        return queryset
    
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer

And I'm getting this output:
Event ID: 24
Comment ID: 2
Queryset: <QuerySet [<Comment: myuser on First event : It was amazing !!>]>
Not Found: /events/24/comments/2/

which means that the query does find the right object, but something is still wrong because I'm getting 404:
HTTP 404 Not Found
Allow: GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "detail": "No Comment matches the given query."
}

